# unable to run OpenOffice from text mode

Tags: linux, command-line, installation, redhat-enterprise-linux, rpm

I have installed OpenOffice in Redhat5 in text mode.  When I tried to start OpenOffice using the command:

```
sudo /usr/lib/openoffice/program/soffice "-accept=socket,host=localhost,port=8100;    urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager " -nologo -headless -nofirststartwizard: "
```

It shows the error saying

```
javaldx: Could not find a Java Runtime Environment!
```

So I installed jre in  my system, and then I did not get any error but OpenOffice does not start.  Also I checked the process regarding OpenOffice, but I haven's seen any process related to that.

Can any one help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you install JRE as a RedHat package? Did you re-install openoffice afterward? Did you consider using Libreoffice?

Comment: why `sudo`? it may be your problem - sometimes, i fyou want to run sth as super user, `sudo` is not enough, you have to login as root.

Answer (score 0):

```
ooffice -writer
```

This, entered in a terminal, will open OpenOffice Writer.